# Concatenation of new line- Perl

Tags: perl

I want to replace a string "hello" with "#hello" . "\nHi".. 
Here is what I have done..

```
#!/perl/bin/perl
use strict;
use Tie::File;

my $filename = "abc.txt";
tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $filename or die;

for(my $i=0; ; $i++) {
    last if !defined $lines[$i]; 

    if($lines[$i]= /^[\s]*hello*/){
        $lines[$i] = "#" . $lines[$i] . "\nHi";
        last;
    }
```

But new line thing isn't working. Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Tie::File docs](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/Tie-File-0.98/lib/Tie/File.pm):

> Inserting records that contain the record separator string is not supported by this module. It will probably produce a reasonable result, but what this result will be may change in a future version. Use 'splice' to insert records or to replace one record with several.

Comment: Ok...So there was no way I can do this with Tie. Is there any other way I can do this thing?

Comment: It say right there, "Use `splice` to insert records or replace one record with several." `splice @lines, $i, 1, "#$line", "Hi";` should work. (Haven't tested though)